# chtag does not work on z/OS UNIX

Tags: posix, mainframe, code-page, zos

I'm trying to tag ASCII files on z/OS host shell, so we do not have to specify the code page on the command line.

```
> echo > iso.txt
> chtag -t -c 819 iso.txt
> vi iso.txt
```

Type in "Hello" then quit and save

```
> ls -T iso.txt
t ISO8859-1   T=on  iso.txt
> od -x iso.txt
0000000000      C885    9393    9615
```

examining the `iso.txt` file shows it contains EBCDIC.

How do I set the tools to make use of the code page tag attribute? Note that explicitly specifying the code page using `-W filecodeset=819` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are support mechanisms for doing auto conversion based on tagging.  To do what you’re interested in, I replicated your scenario on my z/OS 2.3 system.  To accomplish what you want you can set `_BPXK_AUTOCVT=ON`.  I repeated the provided test case and then set `_BPXK_AUTOCVT=ON` to demonstrate the desired behaviour worked.

```
$ echo > iso.txt
$ chtag -t -c 819 iso.txt
$ ls -T iso.txt
t ISO8859-1   T=on  iso.txt
$ vi iso.txt  (enter Hello, save then exit)
$ od -x iso.txt
0000000000      C885    9393    9615
0000000006
```

**The word Hello is stored as EBCDIC despite having tagged the file as 819.

Next, setting `_BPXK_AUTOCVT=ON` enables auto conversion.**

```
$ export _BPXK_AUTOCVT=ON
$ echo > iso.txt
$ chtag -t -c 819 iso.txt
$ vi iso.txt  (enter Hello, save then exit)
$ od -X iso.txt
0000000000          48656C6C        6F0A0000
0000000006
```

**Here you can see that the auto-conversion function stored the text in the correct codeset.**

References:

- [IBM Doc on relevant Environment Variables](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbcpx01/setenv.htm#setenv)
- [File Tagging and Conversion](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbcpx01/cbc1p273.htm)

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/519094/5132 on _Unix and Linx_.